# T4MVC: Strongly typed partial?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

I'm using T4MVC in my MVC 5 website. In a view, I have something like:

```
@Html.Partial(MVC.Shared.Views.ViewNames.Foo, Model.FooBar)
```

The Foo view expects a certain type, which is defined with @model, but Model.FooBar might have a different type. This error is not detected until runtime.

Is there a way to use T4MVC to render the partial with a typed method, like we can use ActionLinks, maybe something like:

```
@Html.Partial(MVC.Shared.Views.Foo(Model.FooBar))  // Error: Foo() expects Argument of type ...
```

Comment: I believe views are compiled at run time only, which is when their type safety is enforced.  Views are type safe, but only at run time.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is that T4MVC currently doesn't support fully strong typing this scenario.

It's something that could conceivably be done, but it would present challenges. Specifically, T4MVC would need to parse the view to determine the model type. Currently, it never parses views, but only detects their existence.

Comment: that would be the single reason for us to switch to T4MVC. the disconnect between view models and partials are one of the most common failure points. they are not detected in compile time either.